# how to use fields from custom block in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-theming

Im new to drupal 8. This is my first time building a site so please help. I have created a custom block type by going to structure/block layout/ types/ add custom block type - 'Feature Boxes'. This block type has 4 fields for the 4 dif images, and 4 fields for the 4 dif links. How can i use the data from each field in my page--front.html.twig file.

Comment: easiest way I can think of would be to place it in the template with the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

Comment: Always is the same as in node in Drupal 7, you can manage your block display, select fields formatters, create field groups and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this module:
[Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

Examples can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x):

I'm not familiar with adding fields to blocks.